# Como tomar los porcentajes bien en reporte pie teleriks Q3 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

Muy buenas tardes, estoy tratando de crear un reporte en teleriks con el asistente, tratando de hacer un pie, donde muestre el porcentaje de proyectos cancelados vs los proyectos creados, la gráfica me la hace bien, sin embargo me da todos los valores al 100%, cuando debería darme los proyectos cancelados 18%.

Este es mi query en SQL Server:

```
SELECT FORMAT((((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Proyectoes WHERE estatusId = (SELECT idEstado FROM estatus WHERE Estatus = 'Canceled')) *100/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Proyectoes))),'') AS 'Canceled Projects Percentage',
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Proyectoes) AS 'Total Projects',
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Proyectoes WHERE estatusId = (SELECT idEstado FROM estatus WHERE Estatus = 'Canceled')) AS 'Total Canceled'
```

Este es el resultado:

> Canceled Projects Percentage 18
>
> Total Projects 2
>
> Total Canceled 11

Y esta es la gráfica que me crea el wizard

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta seria, ¿Cómo hacer que el reporte me de los verdaderos porcentajes en vez de darme 100% en todo?